# How to make a scrollable viewport with elements stack based on content's dimensions?

Tags: html, css

Question: How do I make a the `<main>` element a scrollable container and have cards inside stack on top of another and wrap?

*Note: the cards will always be the same height and width.*

[image]

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
}

.d1 {
  background: black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 40px auto;
}

nav {
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(255,255,255,0.4);
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
  justify-items: center;
}

nav>* {
  padding: 5px 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 5px;
}

.top {
  background: #500;
}

.bot {
  background: #055;
}

.circle-btn {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 32px;
}

.scrollable {
  color: white;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  flex-direction: wrap;
  gap: 12px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.card {
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
  <nav>
    <div class="top">
      <div class="circle-btn"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bot">
      <div class="circle-btn"></div>
      <div class="circle-btn"></div>
      <div class="circle-btn"></div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <div class="scrollable">
      <div class="card">1</div>
      <div class="card">2</div>
      <div class="card">3</div>
      <div class="card">4</div>
      <div class="card">5</div>
      <div class="card">6</div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See about this. The black area is now scrollable instead of the entire document.  I'm not totally sure what you means about the cards stacking, since they kinda already seem to do that with the `display:grid` you are using.

I moved `class="scrollable"` directly onto the `<main>` element instead of being on an inner element

for the `html,body` selector I used `height: 100vh;` and `width: 100vw;` instead of `100%` for each of those.

I removed `width:100%;` on `.d1` and `.scrollable`

```css
html, body {
  height: 100vh; /* <-- Changed from 100% */
  width: 100vw;  /* <-- Changed from 100% */
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
}

.d1 {
  background: black;
  height: 100%;
  /*width: 100%;*/
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 40px auto;
}

nav {
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(255,255,255,0.4);
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
  justify-items: center;
}

nav>* {
  padding: 5px 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 5px;
}

.top {
  background: #500;
}

.bot {
  background: #055;
}

.circle-btn {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 32px;
}

.scrollable {
  color: white;
  padding: 1em;
  /*width: 100%;*/
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); /*<-- Define the # of columns you want here*/
  /*flex-direction: wrap;*/ /*<-- This isn't valid for a grid layout*/
  gap: 12px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.card {
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px){
  /*Define the # of columns you want when the screen is 768px or wider */
  .scrollable {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr); 
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
  <nav>
    <div class="top">
      <div class="circle-btn"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bot">
      <div class="circle-btn"></div>
      <div class="circle-btn"></div>
      <div class="circle-btn"></div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <main class="scrollable">
      <div class="card">1</div>
      <div class="card">2</div>
      <div class="card">3</div>
      <div class="card">4</div>
      <div class="card">5</div>
      <div class="card">6</div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh about stacking, I want the card to fill out the horziontal width of viewport, and they are tightly packed against another based on some gap size. if the cards were to go beyond the viewport width than I would like them to wrap.

Comment: updated with new image

Comment: I'm actually not familar enough with grid layout to know exactly how to do that with just 2 columns!  I was able to get it to define more columns when the screen is larger though.  Perhaps that's your solution: just have a good number of columns defined at each screen size you need so the cards appear close enough together

Comment: it doesn't have to be grid. and it doesn't have to be 2 columns. Its more like on mobile in portrait only 2 columns fit and in desktop 1920x1080 more "N" number of columsns fit cards.

Comment: See at the end where I have the `@media` query, just add as many of those as you want and define the number of columns for each size.  It defaults to 2, you can set a width to show 3 columns at, 4, etc.

Comment: https://codepen.io/matthewharwood/pen/XWyvxdW figured it out

Comment: Bleh doesn't scroll now... I'll need to look more